# Check condition for hexadecimal number

Tags: c#

I have a hexadecimal number written in the text file. I need to check the condition for hexadecimal number in if-else. For example, the Start Number written in the text file is 1100 and End Number is 10FF. The start number,1100 is the addition of End number with 1. This increment process done by other system.

In my case, the system will proceed to the next process after read the numbers in the text file.

This is my code:

```
var data = File                 
.ReadAllLines(Path)                
.Select(x => x.Split('='))                 
.Where(x => x.Length > 1)                
.ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1]);       
    
Console.WriteLine("Start: {0}", data["Start"]);      
Console.WriteLine("End: {0}", data["End"]);      
    
if (data["Start"] == data["End"]+1)     
{    
      //it will proceed to next process     
}     
else     
{    
    //prompt not meet end number    
}
```

The problem is, the `if (data["Start"] == data["End"]+1)`  does not functioning. How can I resolve this issue? Do I need to convert the hexadecimal number to int first?

Comment: Try converting the strings back to integers first, with `Convert.ToInt32(data["Start"], 16)`.

Comment: Try to run `"10FF" + 1` in the intermediate window. [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oYjRvv).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# if you concatenate string with number, number will get converted to a string and appended to the end of original string:

[image]

If you want to perform some math on your numbers, you need to convert them to correct data type first (in your case - integer).

To do this, you can use one of these commands:

```cs
if (Convert.ToInt32(data["Start"], 16) == Convert.ToInt32(data["End"], 16) + 1)
```

or

```cs
if (int.Parse(data["Start"], NumberStyles.HexNumber) == int.Parse(data["End"], NumberStyles.HexNumber) + 1)
```

They will convert your string that contains hexadecimal number to decimal representation of this number, and then it will behave as a number (addition will work as expected, for example).

Answer (score 0):

`"10FF"` is not `0x10FF`.
In c#, The fact that a string happens to contain text that can be parsed as a hexa-decimal number (or any number for that matter) doesn't mean it will be implicitly converted to that number.
In fact, it's the other way around - c# will implicitly convert the number to a string when using the `+` operator between a string and a number - so `"10FF" + 1` will result with `"10FF1"`.

Note I've started this line with "In c#" - because other languages might not follow the same rules. In T-SQL, for instance, implicit conversions from varchar to int happens all the time and it's a very common "gotcha" for inexperienced devs.

So you need to convert your strings to ints, as Lasse V. Karlsen wrote  in the comments.
You can either do that by using `Convert.ToInt32(string, 16)` or by using `int.Parse(str, NumberStyles.HexNumber)` - if you're sure that the text will always contain the string representation of a hexa-decimal number.

For text that you're not sure about, you better use `int.TryParse` to avoid the risk of a `FormatException` - but note that `TryParse` returns `bool` and the int value is returned via an `out` parameter: `int.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var val)`

Comment: Glad to help :-)